# Extract file string from left side but following 2nd delimiter from right

Tags: unix, awk

Below are the full file names.

```
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh.1234567890.txt
qwertyuiop.1234567890.txt
```

trying to use

```
awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
```

How can i use `awk` command to extract below output.

```
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh 
qwertyuiop
```

Edit

i have a list of files in a directory
i am trying to extract time,size,owner,filename into seperate variables.

for filenames.

```
NAME=$(ls -lrt /tmp/qwertyuiop.1234567890.txt | awk -F'/' '{print $3}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1}')
$ echo $NAME
qwertyuiop
$ 

NAME=$(ls -lrt /tmp/qwertyuiop.abcdefgh.1234567890.txt | awk -F'/' '{print $3}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1}')
$ echo $NAME
qwertyuiop
$
```

expected

```
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
```

Comment: wrt what you're really doing, i.e. parsing the output of `ls`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Could you please do lemme know if my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Taking inspiration from Sundeep sir's solution and adding this following too in this mix.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$(NF-1)=$NF="";sub(/\.+$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'.' '{for(i=(NF-1);i<=NF;i++){$i=""};sub(/\.+$/,"")} 1' OFS="."  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {for(i=(NF-1);i<=NF;i++){$i=""};sub(/\.+$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{                     ##Mentioning BEGIN section of awk program here.
  FS=OFS="."               ##Setting FS and OFS variables for awk to DOT here as per OPs sample Input_file.
}                          ##Closing BEGIN section here.
{
  for(i=(NF-1);i<=NF;i++){ ##Starting for loop from i value from (NF-1) to NF for all lines.
    $i=""                  ##Setting value if respective field to NULL.
  }                        ##Closing for loop block here.
  sub(/\.+$/,"")           ##Substituting all DOTs till end of line with NULL in current line.
}
1                          ##Mentioning 1 here to print edited/non-edited current line here.
'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU awk` and other versions that allow manipulation of `NF`

```
$ awk -F. -v OFS=. '{NF-=2} 1' ip.txt
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
qwertyuiop
```

- `NF-=2` will effectively delete last two fields
- `1` is an awk idiom to print contents of `$0`
- Note that this assumes there are at least two fields in every line, otherwise you'd get an error

Similar concept with `perl`, prints empty line if number of fields in the line is less than 3

```
$ perl -F'\.' -lane 'print join ".", @F[0..$#F-2]' ip.txt
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
qwertyuiop
```

With `sed`, you can preserve lines if number of fields is less than 3

```
$ sed 's/\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$//' ip.txt
qwertyuiop.abcdefgh
qwertyuiop
```